# How to make open graph links work with 301 redirects

Tags: vb.net, seo, facebook-opengraph, http-status-code-301, twitter-card

I am using friendly URLs on a `VB.NET` application and I was sharing the URLs on social media and the image preview was working fine. The link can be shared as follows:

```
example.com/news/123
```

or

```
example.com/news/123/hello-this-is-an-article
```

To avoid sharing two versions of the URL for the same article, I created a `301 redirect` on `Pre_load` to redirect the first link to the second corresponding link. This way, I make sure every visited URL contains the article title at the end.

Right after I applied this logic, the URLs without the article title at the end (first URL) do not show image preview on social media anymore. *Twitter card validator* and *Facebook open graph debugger* says that there was a 301 redirect and that no meta tags were found.

**Below is the code that runs on page `Pre_Load`:**

```
'Comparing URL title with the actual Article title

If strURLTitle <> strArticleTitle Then 
'URL article title either changed or does not exist

    Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently"
    Response.AddHeader("Location", "example.com/news/{ID-in-the-URL}/article-title")

End If
```

**Here is a sample HTML I used:**

```
<meta name='author' content='test' />
<meta name='keywords' content='test,test,test' />
<meta name='description' content='test test test' />
<meta itemprop='name' content='test' />
<meta itemprop='description' content='test' />
<meta itemprop='image' content='https://example.com/img.jpg' />
<meta property='og:title' content='test' />
<meta property='og:description' content='test test test' />
<meta property='og:image' content='https://example.com/img.jpg'' />
<meta property='og:image:secure_url' content='https://example.com/img.jpg'' />
<meta property='og:image:width' content='780' />
<meta property='og:image:height' content='439' />
<meta property='og:site_name' content='test' />
<meta property='og:url' content='https://example.com/news/3710/here-is-the-title' />
<meta property='og:type' content='article' />
<meta property='og:locale' content='ar_AR' />
<meta name='twitter:card' content='summary' />
<meta name='twitter:site' content='https://example.com' />
<meta name='twitter:title' content='test' />
<meta name='twitter:description' content='test test test' />
<meta name='twitter:image' content='https://example.com/img.jpg' />
<base href='https://example.com' />
```

**Problem:**

Testing the link (without the article title) on Twitter Card Validator yields the following Log:

> INFO:  Page fetched successfully 
>   WARN:  No metatags found 
>   WARN:  this card is redirected to
>   news/123/hello-this-is-an-article

Testing the link (without the article title) on Facebook Debugger yields the following log:

> Response Code 400
>  Fetched URL   example.com/news/123
>  Canonical
>   URL   
>  example.com/news/123/hello-this-is-an-article
>  Redirect
>   Path
>   Input URL  example.com/news/123 301 HTTP
>   Redirect  example.com/news/123/hello-this-is-an-article

Is there any way to let the open graph debuggers escape the 301 redirects or display the correct results even if I shared a link without a title at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I was using Arabic characters in the URL, it turned out that I need to Encode the URL to make it work on Facebook and Twitter.

**FIX:**

```
Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently"
Response.AddHeader("Location", "example.com/news/{ID-in-the-URL}/" & HttpUtility.UrlEncode(article-title))

<meta property='og:url' content='https://example.com/news/3710/encoded-url' />
```

**Another Fix:**

Use a canonical URLs:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/news/3710/encoded-url" />
```